# elasticsearch on docker - snapshot and restore - access_denied_exception

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, backup, elasticsearch-snapshot

I created elasticsearch cluster flowing by the article: [Running the Elastic Stack on Docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/current/get-started-docker.html)

After the elasticsearch runs, I need to create snapshot and restore to backup my data.
I modified my elastic-docker-tls.yml file:

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${VERSION}
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=basic 
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true 
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true 
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate 
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.key
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=$ELASTIC_PASSWORD
      - path.repo=/usr/share/elasticsearch/backup
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - databak:/usr/share/elasticsearch/backup
      - certs:$CERTS_DIR
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

    healthcheck:
      test: curl --cacert $CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt -s https://localhost:9200 >/dev/null; if [[ $$? == 52 ]]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${VERSION}
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=basic
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.key
      - path.repo=/usr/share/elasticsearch/backup
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - databak:/usr/share/elasticsearch/backup
      - certs:$CERTS_DIR
    networks:
      - elastic

  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${VERSION}
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=basic
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.key
      - path.repo=/usr/share/elasticsearch/backup
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - databak:/usr/share/elasticsearch/backup
      - certs:$CERTS_DIR
    networks:
      - elastic

  kib01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${VERSION}
    container_name: kib01
    depends_on: {"es01": {"condition": "service_healthy"}}
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      SERVERNAME: localhost
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: https://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: https://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: elastic
      ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: $ELASTIC_PASSWORD
      ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES: $CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      SERVER_SSL_ENABLED: "true"
      SERVER_SSL_KEY: $CERTS_DIR/kib01/kib01.key
      SERVER_SSL_CERTIFICATE: $CERTS_DIR/kib01/kib01.crt
    volumes:
      - certs:$CERTS_DIR
    networks:
      - elastic
volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
  data03:
    driver: local
  databak:
    driver: local
  certs:
    driver: local


networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

After that, I registered a snapshot repository:

```
PUT /_snapshot/my_backup
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/backup/my_backup"
  }
}
```

But, I get the following error message:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "repository_exception",
        "reason" : "[my_backup] cannot create blob store"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "repository_exception",
    "reason" : "[my_backup] cannot create blob store",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "access_denied_exception",
      "reason" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/backup/my_backup"
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

I have searched for solutions on google for 2 days but no solution. Can someone help me? Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `chown` for elasticsearch user in docker volume.

1. Run 
   `ls -l` show all mod of directory in elasticsearch
2. Run 
   `chown elasticsearch /backup`

Comment: ``chown elasticsearch backup`` (remove slash) work well

Comment: ```chown elasticsearch /backup 
chown: changing ownership of '/backup': Operation not permitted```
```chown elasticsearch backupchown: cannot access 'backup': No such file or directory```

Answer (score 0):

For elasticsearch deployed  on kubernetes, the way to do is by  adding an init container in the helm values.yaml

```
extraInitContainers: |
   - name: file-permissions
     image: busybox:1.28
     command: ['chown', '-R', '1000:1000', '/usr/share/elasticsearch/']
     securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
     volumeMounts:
     - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
       name: elasticsearch-master
   - name: create-backup-directory
     image: busybox:1.28
     command: ['mkdir','-p', '/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/backup']
     securityContext:
       runAsUser: 0
     volumeMounts:
     - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
       name: elasticsearch-master        
extraEnvs:
     - name: path.repo
       value: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/backup
```

This will create a folder called backup in /usr/share/elasticsearch/data directory.